# How to get list index of Timer object list in Timer Event Handler

Tags: c#, timer, timertask

My application requires 22 separate timers. So I created a timer list like so.

```
List<Timer> myTimers = new List<Timer>();

for(int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
{
  myTimers.Add(new Timer());
}
```

Then I set settings for the timers

```
foreach(var timer in myTimers)
{
  timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ElapsedTimerEventHandler);
  timer.Interval = 10000;
  timer.Enabled = false;
}
```

I then created a method to start the timer.

```
public void SetTimerMethod(int timerId)
{
  var timer = myTimers.ElementAt(timerId);
  timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

My question is in my Event Handler how do I find out which timer called the event handler. I tried using indexOf(myTimers); on the source object passed to the event handler but that does not work. The reason I need the index position is because I need to update a field in a list of class objects based upon which timer expired. Any help would be appreciated.

I am new to this so I am open to doing this in a different way if this is a bad way of doing what I want to.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want the index and not just the timer, you could use `IndexOf`

```
private ElapsedEventHandler(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var index = myTimers.IndexOf((Timer)sender);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If every timer has the same interval and is started the same time what is the point of having many of them versus one?  Anyway, the `sender` property of the `Elapsed` event is the source timer (see also [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.elapsedeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void ElapsedTimerEventHandler(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   var timerCausingThisEvent = (Timer)source;  // source is the timer
   var timerInList = myTimers.First(t => t == timerCausingThisEvent);
   var index = myTimers.IndexOf(timerCausingThisEvent);
}
```

Comment: My timers are not started at the same time. The timers are started at different times. That is why I have the the timerId passed to the SetTimerMethod.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will try it and mark you answer appropriately.